# Словообразовательный суффикс, "вклинивающийся" в основу

Tags: словообразование, морфология, морфемика, суффиксация

Бывают ли случаи, когда при образовании слова словообразовательный суффикс не присоединяется к основе производящего слова, а "вклинивается" внутрь её? Если да, приведите, пожалуйста, примеры.

Comment: Нет, в русском языке такое исключено. Единственное, что может произойти - переразложение морфемного состава... Возможно какие-то авторы и найдут в каком-то таком переразложении (ну типа слово "взять" - якобы без корня) ваш случай, но все равно это будет крайне спорно.

Comment: @behemothus, спасибо. Но все равно беспокоит, неспроста же вопрос автор придумал...

Comment: @behemothus, кстати, а почему вы не пишете это в ответ? Так было бы правильней, по-моему

Comment: Не стоит оно ответа. Да и не было уверенности, что я правильно вопрос понял. Если уточните формулировку и будут полноценные мысли на этот счет, могу и ответить.

Comment: *Но все равно беспокоит, неспроста же вопрос автор придумал.* - да мало ли, что этому товарищу в голову взбрело. После "почтальона" (которым он по большому счету запутал всех, даже Людмилу) можно всего ожидать. Понимаете, в таких случаях это на 99% - вопрос формулировок и терминологии. Если для "правильного" ответа на вопрос надо проникнуться всем духом авторской (отнюдь не общепринятой!) терминологии, то к черту такой вопрос.Ибо остаётся только менторствовать (как  Галина), объясняя, что автор, грубо говоря, дурак или невежа, или в бессилии развести руками.

Comment: Простите, не "взять" якобы без корня, а "вынуть" (что тоже неверно, если смотреть в корень).

Comment: @behemothus да автор-то другой. Книжку С. И. Львовой я пока отложил (а до этого нашел еще 3 ошибки).

Answer (score 1):

> Бывают ли случаи?..

Бывают. К примеру, при образовании причастий от возвратных глаголов (если считать причастия самостоятельной частью речи):

*бор-о-ть-ся --> бор-**ющ**-ий-ся.*

В приведённом примере суффикс *-ющ-* находится внутри производящей основы *бор...ся.*

При отнесении причастий к самостоятельной части речи их суффиксы рассматриваются как словообразовательные.

.

> Бывают ли случаи?..

"Вклинивание" словообразовательного суффикса внутрь основы производящего слова встречается и при образовании наречий.

Из *"Морфемно-орфографического словаря"* Тихонова:

> Одну из структурных особенностей наречий составляет "вставочное"
>   образование форм оценки: суффиксы оценки не присоединяются к
>   производящей основе, а вставляются внутрь основы перед наречным
>   суффиксом. Например:
>
> *бос/ик-ом —  бос/ич-**к**-ом, ряд-ом —   ряд-**ышк**-ом, <…> част-о
>   —   част-**еньк**-о.*

Comment: В школе причастие - особый вид глагола и суфф. формообразующий

Comment: Нет, не во всех школах. Это в советское время все школы учились по одному учебнику, сейчас же... Литневская говорит о трёх официальных альтернативных учебных комплексах, имеющих гриф Минобразования, рекомендованных им и рассылаемых в школьные библиотеки. И как минимум в двух их них (по её словам) причастие считается самостоятельной частью речи.

Answer (score 0):

[Суффикс](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81&all=x) по определению [аффикс](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81&all=x), находящийся между корнем и окончанием.

Другое дело другой аффикс, именно вклинивающийся в основу слова, прямо-таки в корень, он называется [**инфикс**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81&all=x).

[ИНФИКС. Аффикс, вставляемый внутри основы.](http://literary_terms.academic.ru/218/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81)

> Инфиксом можно считать *о* в русском языке род. мн. *досок;* сначала
>   такое *о* являлось фонетически на месте бывших некогда *ъ* и *ь,*
>   выпадавших в открытых слогах и переходивших в *о* и *е* в закрытых, а
>   потом получило значение формального признака род. мн. от имен на *-а*
>   и благодаря этому проникло по аналогии и туда, где его раньше не было.

Понятно, да? Дос**о**к, крас**о**к, кас**о**к, сказ**о**к, мас**о**к - далее везде.

И ещё парочка глаголов для примера:

> В русском языке имеются чередования, восходящие к носовому
>   индоевропейскому инфиксу: «лечь» — «лягу» «сесть» — «сяду» от leg-ti —
>   le-n-g-o и sed-ti — se-n-do.

[источник-1](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/bse/90890/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81), [источник-2](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81).

Comment: Все-таки инфикс инфиксом (он образует формы слова). Вопрос про словообразовательный суффикс.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, имеются в виду такие сложные  слова,как высокооплачиваемый, высокоуважаемый, малоизученный, малозначимый, малоисследованный, малозаселенный, нижеподписавшийся, нижеуказанный  (и др.), где  о  и е  являются не соединительными гласными, а наречными суффиксами (эти наречия легко выделить: высоко  оплачивать, глубоко  уважать, мало  изучить, мало  исследовать  и т. п.)

Comment: Но это же "словообразовательный суффикс внутри производящей основы" (как автор вопрос ставит). Мало ли какие суффиксы могут залезть в первое из двух составляющих сложного слово?

Comment: Ему же нужно "вклиниваться" в основу, а при сложении основы просто складываются.